# How to get remote branch, overwriting local commits?

Tags: git

I have made some commits in my local `master` branch. Now I want to throw them away and end up with state equal to `origin/master`.

I wouldn't like to `git reset --hard`, because those commits are a result of a fast-forward merge of another branch, so my and remote commits are intermixed.

Currently the only solution that I cant think of is

```
git fetch
git checkout origin/master
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master
git remote origin/master
```

There surely is a much faster way?

Comment: use git stash and git stash apply

Comment: git stash is hide you changes and then you can able to pull the code inside your changes then again run commad git stash apply it will overwrite the code with your changes

Comment: @Ahmer, those are not local changes, but rather commits that I would like to discard.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about having "intermixed commits". `git reset --hard` will point your master at origin/master and you will effectively end up in the exact same state as the remote, no matter what.

Comment: @Pikrass, it appears I never used the command with anything but `HEAD~x`. Thanks for the tip, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: you mean th answer is working?

Answer (score 5):

> I wouldn't like to `git reset --hard`, because those commits are a result of a fast-forward merge of another branch, so my and remote commits are intermixed.

I don’t understand this argumentation.

`git reset --hard origin/master` will reset your currently checked-out branch so it points at exactly the same commit as `origin/master`; and then it will overwrite all files in your working directory to reflect that change.

So if you are currently on your local `master` branch, then this is the command that will reset your local branch and working directory to the state of the remote’s `master` branch, effectively throwing away whatever you did locally on that branch.

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

does exactly the same as

```
git checkout origin/master
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master
```

just keep your `git fetch` command to make sure you use the latest information about `origin/master`.

The last command you propose (`git remote origin/master`) is a non-existing command; and I don't see what you want to do. It isn't necessary anyway.